PlayFab CloudScript: How Can I Set a Big Picture In Push Notifications
I have this function that runs on PlayFab cloud script that sends a notification to all users and it works, but how can I set a banner (big picture) in the push notification with a given URL?
handlers.sendPushNotification = (args, context) => {
  try {
    const bigPictureUrl =
      "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/project-id.appspot.com/o/FCMImages%2Fnotification-banner-7.png";
    server.SendPushNotification({
      Recipient: currentPlayerId,
      Package: { Title: "Test", Message: "This is a test" },
    });
    return {};
  } catch (err) {}
};

Here is what I did in Firebase Console and worked with me:

